# Boostrap Carousel Slider not working properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

seems like I am doing something wrong here and I don't know why.
I want the captions and CTA buttons to overlap the image but it's separating between the two. Can anyon help me place the caption on the image, so it works like I intend to do?

[image]

Here's the HTML

```
<div>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item"> <img class="first-slide" src="../assets/img/features/cleardent-header.png" alt="First slide"> 
      <!--slogan and CTA-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row header-slogan fadeInDown animated">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <section class="cd-intro">
              <h1 class="cd-headline letters type"><span>Do everything.</span> <span class="cd-words-wrapper ahwaiting"><b class="is-visible">Better.</b><b class="colour-cleardent">with ClearDent</b></span></h1>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row header-tagline fadeInDown animated">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p>A complete dental practice management program that you are going to <span class="colour-cleardent-sec">love</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row header-cta fadeInUp animated">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button class="btn-u extra-demo-btns" onClick="window.location='../demo';"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Book a Demo</button>
            &nbsp; <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/157093017" class="btn-u fancybox-media fbmloading" id="cleardent-page-header-2-vimeo" data-fancybox-title="Why ClearDent?"><i class="fa fa-play fa-fw"></i> Watch a Video</a> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--slogan and CTA end--> 
    </div>
    <div class="item active"> <img class="second-slide" src="../assets/img/features/cleardent-header.png" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item"> <img class="third-slide" src="../assets/img/features/cleardent-header.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Bootstrap 4, the carousel markup should look like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="" alt=""> 
        <div class="carousel-caption">

            <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you need some of css in order to position your images/captions properly:

```
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 720px; // set your height
}

.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 720px; // set your height
  z-index: 9;
}
```

So you code would be:

```css
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 720px;
}

.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 720px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/1280x720">
   <div class="carousel-caption">

    <!--slogan and CTA-->
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row header-slogan fadeInDown animated">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <section class="cd-intro">
        <h1 class="cd-headline letters type"><span>Do everything.</span> <span class="cd-words-wrapper ahwaiting">
         <b class="is-visible">Better.</b><b class="colour-cleardent">with ClearDent</b></span>
        </h1>
       </section>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row header-tagline fadeInDown animated">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <p>A complete dental practice management program that you are going to <span class="colour-cleardent-sec">love</span></p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row header-cta fadeInUp animated">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
       <button class="btn-u extra-demo-btns" onClick="window.location='../demo';"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Book a Demo</button>
       &nbsp; <a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/157093017" class="btn-u fancybox-media fbmloading" id="cleardent-page-header-2-vimeo" data-fancybox-title="Why ClearDent?"><i class="fa fa-play fa-fw"></i> Watch a Video</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--slogan and CTA end--> 
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/1280x720">
   <div class="carousel-caption">

    <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/1280x720">
   <div class="carousel-caption">

    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
</div>
```